# (yet another) game recommendation question: How to search for a specific set of game mechanics?

Tags: discussion

So, I'm relatively new to StackExchange, and completely new to this forum.  I scanned the various first half dozen or so posts on why game recommendation threads in general were bad for here and what to do instead.

My question relates to the following:   If you have a question of the sort "I'm looking for a game with features X,Y, and Z",  I've already seen plenty of explanations as to why that's unacceptable and suggestions for the alternative, such as board game geek's search site.   However,  using that site I did not see the specific game mechanics I was looking for, which I didn't think was *that* obscure.

So,  with the preamble out of the way,  would a question of the following format be acceptable:   "How would one go about searching for a game with the following criterea?"  That *seems* like it avoids the pitfalls that are wanted to avoided.  (Big list questions, opinion questions,  questions without closed answers, questions that would not be of use to future users).    But it skirts pretty close to things that seem to be verbotten, so I thought I'd ask here first.

Comment: Just a heads up, try not to call a Stack Exchange site a 'forum'. For some reason, people go absolutely freaking insane if you call it a forum. "Oh, we're not like those *forums*." Even though, you know, a forum is simply a venue for communication, which SE sites totally are. They just get pissy when you say it. Just letting you know. =)

Answer (score 2):

It will probably be fine. The only precedent I can find for your type of question is [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13636/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-cooperative-beat-the-game-games), which stayed open and was pretty well received.

The advice I usually like to give for these kinds of questions is: just try asking it. In the worst case, your question gets closed and maybe a few downvotes.